Merging timelike and spacelike surfaces
In the following paper there is a statement which says:

We propose to determine the boundary length by merging smoothly the
timelike and spacelike surfaces in such a way that they are homologous
to the boundary and have a well-defined first derivative at the
merging point.

Can this procedure be done in the case of thermal AdS, where the boundary is at infinity?

How do you take a derivative at infinity?

The question isn't very clear about what it wants: what are you trying to do here? In AdS the boundary is at spatial infinity, yes, but what about it?

@VaibhavK, if you read the paper, you will see that they use a soliton background and cigar geometry since their work deals with confinement. Now, if I wish to work in the thermal AdS phase, the soliton background is unnecessary. In that case, how to follow the same procedure is the concern here.
